# Is there a way to customize the owner of extraDirectories added by jib?

Tags: jib

We're trying to add extraDirectories using jib to add a couple app-specific files, but we'd prefer the files to be owned by a user that exists in the base image, and not owned by root. We need the files to be writable by the user, but don't want them writable by others.

I know you can use extraDirectories.permissions to set *permissions* on the paths, but is there a way to set owner and group of the files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the *Jib Ownership Extension* (for [Maven](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib-extensions/tree/master/first-party/jib-ownership-extension-maven) and [Gradle](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib-extensions/tree/master/first-party/jib-ownership-extension-gradle)).

The main Jib plugin purposely does not allow changing ownership, but with the Jib Ownership Extension, you can change the ownership of any files as long as they are placed by Jib.

---

**Bonus: what is a Jib Extension?**

Just FYI, Jib has its own extension mechanism and allows anyone to write an extension to tweak the behavior of Jib. If you want to learn more about the general Jib extension framework or browse other useful Jib extensions, check out the [jib-extensions](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib-extensions) GitHub repo.